# Identifying elements in a tuple

Tags: python

I want to see if in a tuple of three elements there are two identical elements and a zero. Here's an example:

```
Hello = (1, 1, 0)
Hi = (1, 0, -1)
Greetings = (0, -1, 1)
```

`Hello` has two numbers that are the same (and numbers besides 0 will only be -1 or 1) and the other two don't.

If there is a 0 and the rest is occupied by `n` (`n` can be either 1 or -1) then can I create a function that "reads" my tuple and sees if there is two elements equal to each other and one equal to 0?

I started coding and this is what I got:

```
tab = ((1,1,0),(1,0,-1),(0,-1,1))

def line(tab, l):
    if l == 1:
        return (tab[0][0],tab[0][1],tab[0][2])
    elif l == 2:
        return (tab[1][0],tab[1][1],tab[1][2])
    elif l == 3:
        return (tab[2][0],tab[2][1],tab[2][2])
    else:
        return ValueError('invalid')

def identify(n):
    if line(tab, 1)[0] == n and line(tab, 1)[1] == n and line(tab, 1)[2] == 0:
        print('2nd position')
    elif line(tab, 1)[0] == n and line(tab, 1)[1] == 0 and line(tab, 1)[2] == n:
        print('1st position')
    elif line(tab, 1)[0] == 0 and line(tab, 1)[1] == n and line(tab, 1)[2] == n:
        print('0º position')
    elif line(tab, 2)[0] == n and line(tab, 2)[1] == n and line(tab, 2)[2] == 0:
        print('2nd position')
    elif line(tab, 2)[0] == n and line(tab, 2)[1] == 0 and line(tab, 2)[2] == n:
        print('1st position')
    elif line(tab, 2)[0] == 0 and line(tab, 2)[1] == n and line(tab, 2)[2] == n:
        print('0º position')
    elif line(tab, 3)[0] == n and line(tab, 3)[1] == n and line(tab, 3)[2] == 0:
        print('2nd position')
    elif line(tab, 3)[0] == n and line(tab, 3)[1] == 0 and line(tab, 3)[2] == n:
        print('1st position')
    elif line(tab, 3)[0] == 0 and line(tab, 3)[1] == n and line(tab, 3)[2] == n:
        print('0º position')
    else:
        raise ValueError('invalid')
```

As you can see the code is huge (but I think the fundamentals are OK) but it doesn't run. What can be the problem?

Comment: The body of your `identify` function isn't indented...

Comment: You never defined n

Answer (score 1):

identify() needed an argument and it didn't have one. the argument is "n"

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you found the syntax error, but if you encounter further problems with this code, I'd suggest this as a simpler alternative to individually checking each possible permutation:

```
from typing import Tuple

def two_identical_and_a_zero(t: Tuple[int, int, int]) -> bool:
    non_zero = [e for e in t if e != 0]
    if len(non_zero) == 0:
        return True   # all zeroes
    if len(non_zero) != 2:
        return False  # odd number of zeroes
    return non_zero[0] == non_zero[1]

tab = [
    (1, 1, 0),
    (1, 0, -1),
    (0, -1, 1),
]

for t in tab:
    print(f"{t}: {'Valid' if two_identical_and_a_zero(t) else 'Invalid'}")
```

prints:

```
(1, 1, 0): Valid
(1, 0, -1): Invalid
(0, -1, 1): Invalid
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't see how I can apply this to the problem I have (still new to python). Imagine that line(tab, 1) is my tuple with three elements. How can I apply this function?

Comment: `two_identical_and_a_zero(line(tab, 1))`.

Comment: The `line` function is also unnecessary, I think; I updated my answer to just go through your `tab` tuples and print whether each is valid or invalid.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does the trick:

```
tab = ((1,1,0),(1,0,-1),(0,-1,1))
for tup in tab:
     a = 0
     b = 0
     c = 0
     for num in tup:

        if num == -1:
            a += 1
        if num == 0:
            b += 1
        if num == 1:
            c += 1
    if (a == 2 and b == 1) or (c == 2 and b == 1):
        print('Task accomplished')
    else:
        print('Invalid')
```

output:

```
Task accomplished
Invalid
Invalid
```

Comment: I couldn't put it to work. After tab I created a function for the rest with argument tab (for examplen, def yup(tab):) but it says that it stops working on the line "if (a == 2 and b == 1) or (c == 2 and b == 1):"

Comment: If you will create a function you need to have tup as input as it is above, not tab. When I wrote 'tup for tab' above it goes through each tuple in your list of tuples and checks each one. Another option would to copy the code exactly as I send it and check that it works

Answer (score 1):

I would turn the tuple into a list, that way it would be easier to check for a 0 in any element. If so, add all the elements and check whether they sum to 2 or -2. There are many other ways to check if the other two are either 1 or -1, I think summing them is elegant enough, but keep in mind it only works if they can be either 1 or -1 as you wrote.
Example:

```
def identify_tuple(my_tuple):
    my_list = list(my_tuple)
    if 0 in my_list:
        list_sum = sum(my_list)
        if list_sum == 2 or list_sum == -2:
            return True
    return False
```